# $\mathcal{O}_K$ analogous to $\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

The definition of $\mathcal{O}_K$ isn't very well explained or motivated in my textbook.

> Let $K$ be a field a field with $\mathbb{Q} \subset K \subset \mathbb{C}$. $\mathcal{O}_K$ consists of all elements of $K$ which are roots of a normed polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}$, that means
>   $$x^n + s_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \cdots + s_1 x + s_0 = 0 \quad \text{ for } n \in \mathbb{N}, s_i \in \mathbb{Z} \, .$$

Now, later this theorem is proven:

> For any element $x \in K$ there is an $n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $n x$ in $\mathcal{O}_K$.

From which a corollary *"$K$ is the field of fractions of $\mathcal{O}_K$"* follows.

But is $\mathcal{O}_K$ the *smallest* subring of $K$ which has this property? IMHO only then $\mathcal{O}_K$ can really be called analogous to $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Q}$, but this wasn't proven.

Comment: In general there isn't such a smallest subring. For example, in $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ you can take subrings of the form $\mathbb{Z}[Ni]$ for any integer $N$. $\mathcal{O}_K$ just turns out to be a very convenient ring to work with for reasons which you'll learn if you get further in your textbook.

Answer (score 1):

What you are referring to is the so called *[ring of integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_of_integers)* in algebraic number theory. The set up is as follows:

You have $\mathbb{Q}\subset K$ as a finite field extension. Inside of $K$, let $\mathcal{O}_{K}$ be the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}$. Then you have:
$$
\mathbb{Z}\subset\mathcal{O}_{K}\subset K
$$
as well as $K$ is the fractional field of $\mathcal{O}_{K}$. $\mathcal{O}_{K}$ is the smallest ring inside of $K$ with this property(subring of $K$ and fractional field is $K$), because the rank $\mathcal{O}_{K}$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$ module is the same as $K:\mathbb{Q}$, otherwise we will be missing elements in $K$. So we at least need a subring of $K$ with the same rank as $\mathcal{O}_{K}$ over $\mathbb{Z}$. But then we would not have a good criterion to compare $\mathcal{O}_{K}$ with a different subring of $K$ unless one is inside of the other. However we know $\mathcal{O}_{K}\cong \mathbb{Z}^{n}$ additively, so its only subring (not ideal) of rank $n$ must be itself. There may be other ones inside of $K$ overlap but not inside of $\mathcal{O}_{K}$ as Qiaochu pointed out.

By the way, it make no sense to say $\mathbb{Z}$ is the "smallest ring with this property". There is no strict subring of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I meant that $\mathcal{O}_K$ is the smallest subring with the property that its fraction field is $K$. $\mathbb{Z}$ is a subring of $K$, but doesn't have this property.

Comment: @aRaRa: You made the analogy between $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$. So I thought you want to check all $\mathbb{Z}$'s smaller subrings would not work or something. Otherwise I cannot see where the analogy coming from.